# SQL Query count when true for record

Tags: sql, count

I am working with a table that resembles the below model, which we use to track subscriptions to products.

| ID | Product1 | Product2 | CountProduct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | true | false | ## |
| 456 | true | true | ## |

I am attempting to use SQL to input the CountProduct value. It should reflect the number of products that are equal to true for the record in question.

So the output should look like this:

| ID | Product1 | Product2 | CountProduct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | true | false | 1 |
| 456 | true | true | 2 |

I have the flexibility to update the model and queries but looking for a way to store, in a single table, the number and which products each person is subscribed to. I need each record to be a unique person and I have other personalized data included.

I have tried researching if this is even possible, but can't find the right wording or even whether others do this.

Comment: I'd say redesign. Have one row per product instead, and a product_type column.

Comment: Something like SELECT CASE WHEN Product1='true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Product2='true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as CountProduct FROM...  ?

Comment: @Elliveny this worked! I feel so dumb for not thinking of this myself. You wouldn't believe the circles I ran myself into.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. I wasn't sure which DBMS you're using and wondered whether those true/false were strings or a proper boolean type? I might be able to advise a slightly more optimal method if you could advise

Answer (score 0):

from @elliveny in the comments:

Something like

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN Product1='true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Product2='true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as CountProduct FROM...
```